# What is file_key argument in import_public_link()?

Tags: python

I am trying to import a public link to my mega folder using MEGA'S Python API with This Code but getting an Error which is saying `import_public_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_key'`.

Code:

```
from mega import Mega
mega = Mega()

client = mega.login('email', 'password')

folder = client.find('Folder')[0]

client.import_public_file('https://mega.nz/file/bgJ3yA5I#fmFDN9vJZnhHMBQPNheEsm72QBYskzSm6vmwGFcBPHo',
    dest_node=folder)
```

I would love to know what is `file_key` argument, Thank you!

Comment: Did you want to use import_public_url instead? It gets only url. While import_public_file gets both url and key.

Comment: I tried to replace .nz with .co.nz but still didn't work. here is a screenshot of arguments that import_public_file() function wants [Image](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/812287293897179159/897431424536305674/unknown.png?width=604&height=47)

Comment: There's a new comment with another question about method used. :)

Comment: Oh DAMN, Thank you! I was typing file instead of url.

Comment: Without typing 'folder' it works fine but with it, it gets an error `string indices must be integers`. Do you know whats the right way of defining a folder?

Comment: Fixed it by typing [1] instead of [0] while finding it with the find() function